# Can I create a spring bean as part of my cucumber step definitions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java

For some context, my spring boot application makes calls to external APIs providing the current date using `LocalDate.now()` and retrieves various information back. We are using Cucumber for testing and the above presents a problem when writing step definitions such as

```
Given external api "/some/endpoint/2021-04-21" returns csv
  | currency |
  | GBP      |
```

The step definition test code uses wiremock to mock that call, but since we are using `LocalDate.now()` in the production code, the test will fail for any day other than 2021-04-21.

The way I have gotten around this is by defining two beans for [Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) that we can then autowire into the services that require them and use `LocalDate.now(clock)`. The "real" bean is defined like so:

```
@Configuration
public class ClockConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
    }
}
```

And the test bean like so:

```
@Profile("cucumber")
@TestConfiguration
public class ClockConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.fixed(Instant.parse("2021-02-26T10:00:00Z"), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

This solves my problem and allows me to set a defined time for my tests, but my problem is that the date/time is defined in the test configuration. I would like to define it as part of my step definitions. For example something like

```
Given now is "2021-02-26T10:00:00Z"
```

Have a step definition along the lines of

```
@Given("now is {string})
public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    //Create Clock bean here...
}
```

Is there a way for me to do this? Or to even overwrite the existing bean during the cucumber step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find two working solutions to this problem. The first was a bit more complicated but I essentially created a wrapper class around `Clock`, so an interface with a method `Clock getClock()` which then had two implementations. One was the real bean that would just return `Clock.systemDefaultZone()` and a test bean that had a private Clock member that the getter would just return, but most important a setter like

```
public void setClock(String dateTime) {
    this.clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(dateTime), ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

I would then call this setter as part of step definition method by getting the bean e.g.

```
@Given("now is {string})
public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    applicationContext.getBean(MyWrapperClock.class).setClock(dateTime);
}
```

---

The 2nd method I found was much simpler, and was to simply mock the clock in the test configuration file e.g.

```
@Bean 
public Clock clock() {
    return Mockito.mock(Clock.class);
}
```

And then autowire this in to the step definition class and just do a normal mockito `when` such as

```
@Given("now is {string})
public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    when(this.clock.instant()).thenReturn(Instant.parse(dateTime));
    when(this.clock.getZone()).thenReturn(ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the date with a variable or a static method the response of which can be altered by the step definition.

```
@Profile("cucumber")
@TestConfiguration
public class ClockConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Clock clock() {
        return Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(TestScope.getDateValue()), ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }
}
```

```
@Given("now is {string})
public void setDateTime(String dateTime) {
    TestScope.setDateValue(dateTime);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work because the bean is created before the step definition is called, and therefore throws a NPE as the date in TestScope has no value.